# WPF/C# - ´binding list<string> to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, combobox

I want my combobox item names and values to be taken from my List of course I don't want my view model to hold combobox items list.

I got a list a,b,c,d

```
public List<String> ComboList { get; set; }
```

...

```
ComboList = new List<String>();
ComboList.Add("A");
ComboList.Add("B");
ComboList.Add("C");
ComboList.Add("D");
```

and my ComboBox

`<ComboBox Margin="29,40,0,526" Width="212" Height="35" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboList, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"></ComboBox>`

but it gives me a empty ComboBox ...

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting Key/Value from. Is this a Dictionary and not a List?

Comment: hehe, yeah, it's always the obvious things that cause the most headache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` attributes.  They are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to do that just before the InitializeComponents into the code-behind :

```
public void MainWindow(){
  this.Datacontext = this;
  InitializeComponent()
}
```

Moreover you cannot bind the list directly, you better have to give an ObservableCollection.
This is an example :

```
public ObservableCollection<NetworkCard> NetworksCards { get { return m_aCards; } }

private ObservableCollection<NetworkCard> m_aCards = null;
m_aCards = new ObservableCollection<NetworkCard>(oHelper.ListNetworkCards());
```